# Custom AnimationClock for WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm searching for a way to have a custom AnimationClock. Every Storyboard has it's own and under heavy load the animations get out of sync. Since I need to have separate Completed events making one big Storyboard impossible...

The solution I'm currently investigation is to write a custom AnimationClock class, so that the animation stays in sync as the AnimationClock for all of the affected Storyboards starts and stops at exactly the same time.

I did not found a way to implement this yet, and internet searches have revealed only unanswered threads until now. Has anyone found a solution to create a custom clock?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe my article (in Italian translated with google) can help you http://translate.google.it/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=it&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.ugidotnet.org%2Fleonardo%2Farchive%2F2011%2F01%2F08%2Fsincronizziamo-le-animazioni-con-wpf.aspx&act=url. You need to call ReSync() every time you go out of sync.

Comment: An interesting solution. The problem solved as a redesign of the UI rendered synchronization obsolete.